# How to pass an Event Object into a nested function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I pass an event object into a nested function and have it be understood by the script?

Below is not my actual code but it illustrates the issue. The function there cannot complete, because `evt.target.src` is out of scope, I guess.  Again, this is dumbed down code.  I'm only asking how can the `evt.target.src` be understood from inside this nested function.

```js
SomeFunction =(evt)=> {
  setTimeout(
    ()=> {evt.target.src = somethingIcreated}, 200
  )
};
```

If I assign it to a variable outside of the nested function to pass in, it's just understood as some random variable, not the actual event object's `src`. Thus the `src` won't change or the project will crash because it cannot work with something that is null.

Comment: What you have there will work just fine...assuming this isn't using a framework like React that does simulated events.

Comment: It's REACTJS... haha :o/

Comment: why do you want access event after its life has ended this can cause some memory leaks?

Comment: @t.j.crowder that was quite a good educated guess ...

Comment: Basically without getting too detailed, I have a grid of profile face images, and when you click on one the image switches for a moment to them getting hit in the face.  I realize there are several ways I can do this, but this way seems to make the most economical sense to me.  It's a personal "sand box" project, to help me learn the behavior and syntax nuances of React.

Answer (score 2):

React uses synthetic events and it reuses them, so you're not allowed to use them after the handler returns.

You have two choices:

1. You can grab properties from them and them later. So in your case:

   ```
   SomeFunction = ({target}) => {
     setTimeout(
       ()=> {target.src = somethingIcreated}, 200
     )
   };
   ```

   There, I'm using destructuring in the parameter list to grab the `target` property from the event object, which it's okay to reuse later. It's just the event object itself that you can't use after the handler returns.
2. You can use the `persist` method on the event to tell React you want to keep it.

More in the [synthetic events documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

Comment: Thanks T.J., #1 worked out perfectly.  Both are things I've never seen before (I'm new, I haven't seen a lot), so I will have a field day with both of them.  I'm a little concerned with the last sentence on your number 1, but I don't foresee any problems at the moment.